# difference between flash and flex objects?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Adobe Flex? Is it just Flash II?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083/what-is-adobe-flex-is-it-just-flash-ii)

Can some one tell me in layman's term as to whats the difference between flex and flash objects. i know that programmatically there are differences and there  are difference in the extension but then why do some flex programs have a .swf extension since the extension for flex is swc ? .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is not big difference between the flex and flash. Flash is more oriented or specially designed software for designer because they can create anything without using any code. Coding is the advantage for the designer to save his time but he can also perform the same work without coding. Flash provides number of tools for drawing to create graphics or timeline method for changing those graphics according to the requirement. Flash is used to create web ads, banner for websites, banner for social messages, games, and so on. Using Action Script in the flash we can make our design more lively or realistic. The biggest disadvantage of flash is you have to spend countless hours for creating attractive framework for your project or website. It is really a time consuming process.

Where as flex is more oriented or created to keep in mind the developers. It has includes almost every feature of web development. Developers who have good knowledge of html, css and javascript or little bit designing knowledge can easily understand the flex. You can create graphics by using inbuilt components or functions. The prime function of php is to create business type applications. If you want create complex application in other software it will take number of hours to complete but flex provides the framework applications which includes inbuilt components to design or develop complex application and with the use of components you will save your time. You can use several languages in one application like mxml which is similar to html, action script or php, dotnet and so on. Flex compiles these languages in one SWF file. The only disadvantage of flex is that it doesn't provide any tool for designing but with the use of stylesheet, properties or components we can develop or design attractive design for our applications.